# Select lines in order with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, sorting

I am looking for a solution to order my loop selection. My problem is that when is select the rows, these aren't sorted. So I want to find the all matching lines and process them after that find the next matching lines based on the next key word. An other aspect I want firtly I want to find the all matching lines first and after that the all matching line based n the  next key word. Finally I would like to note that I do not want to append the result in different variables because I have many key word.

**Here is a simple example of my problem:**

```
key_word=['one', 'two']
list=['one1', 'one2', 'two1', 'two2', 'two3', 'one3']

for i in list:
    for word in key_word:
        if (word in i):
            print (i)
```

**My output:**

```
one1
one2
two1
two2
two3
one3
```

**My desired output:**

```
one1
one2
one3
two1
two2
two3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of loops.

```
key_word=['one', 'two']
lst=['one1', 'one2', 'two1', 'two2', 'two3', 'one3']


for word in key_word:
    for i in lst:
        if (word in i):
            print (i)
```

Comment: Ohh te answer was so simple, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First get list of all the items that have keyword, and then iterate over them.
Here's how you can do this:

```
key_word=['one', 'two']
lst=['one1', 'one2', 'two1', 'two2', 'two3', 'one3']


for i in key_word:
    l = [k for k in lst if i in k]

    for word in l:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Ohh te answer was so simple, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Quick one using list comrehension

```
key_word=['one', 'two']
lst=['one1', 'one2', 'two1', 'two2', 'two3', 'one3']

print("\n".join(sorted([x for x in lst if key_word[0] in x or key_word[1] in x])))
```